# Getting JSON data from snowflake stored procedure parameter and inserting it in target table

Tags: javascript, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement to receive JSON data in a Stored Proc parameter and insert the same in the snowflake target table (user_json_feedback). JSON Data has three key elements(User, EntityID, and Entity Type), whereas the target table has five columns (User, ID, Entity Type, Region, and Date). The region will have a default value of "NA," and the date will be the current date.

If the inserts are successful, it returns true; otherwise, it returns false.

I am struggling with the syntax and parsing issues here, as I am very new to writing procedures.

Here is what I have been trying to do, which is giving me errors obviously but serves the algorithm of my intent.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SP_UPDATE_JSON_DATA (JSON_DATA VARIANT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN 
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 
$$   
//Declare variables  
var REGION = 'NA'
var V_DATE = `select current_date;`;
var DATE_STMT= snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: V_DATE });
var curr_date = DATE_STMT.execute();
var src_json = JSON.parse(JSON_DATA);    
var sql_command =
`INSERT INTO user_json_feedback (user,id,etype,region ,date)//
select src_json:USER,src_json:ENTITY_ID,src_json:ENTITY_TYPE,REGION,curr_date;`;
try {
    snowflake.execute (
        {sqlText: sql_command}
        );
    return "Succeeded.";   // Return a success/error indicator.
    }
catch (err)  {
    return "Failed: " + err;   // Return a success/error indicator.
    }
$$;
```

The function call with parameters will be like

```
call SP_UPDATE_JSON_DATA ('[{"USER":"XYZ","ENTITY_ID":"BMT0001","ENTITY_TYPE":"BMT"},{"USER":"ABC","ENTITY_ID":"BMT0002","ENTITY_TYPE":"BMT"}]');
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

theres a few things here.

Firstly the step to get current date. curr_date is a result set object. to extract the value and use it later, you need to read the first row with .next() then GetColumnValue to read the column content. to pass it later as a well formatted string you'll wanna convert with .toISOString().

Secondly the parsed json returns an array in this case so you'll need to iterate over the array to insert the individual records. As it's not known ahead of time if the variant will contain an array you're best checking if the parsed json is an array and handle it accordingly

Last tweak was altering the return type so you get the verbose feedback you're expecting from your return calls.

Updated code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE user_json_feedback
(
     user   VARCHAR(100)     
    ,id     VARCHAR(100) 
    ,etype  VARCHAR(100)     
    ,region VARCHAR(100)     
    ,date   TIMESTAMP_NTZ
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY PROCEDURE SP_UPDATE_JSON_DATA(JSON_DATA VARIANT)
RETURNS STRING 
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 
$$   
//Declare variables  
var REGION = 'NA'
var V_DATE = `select current_date;`;
var DATE_STMT= snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: V_DATE });
var DATE_STMT_RES = DATE_STMT.execute();
DATE_STMT_RES.next()
var curr_date = DATE_STMT_RES.getColumnValue(1).toISOString();
var src_json = JSON.parse(JSON_DATA);    

try {
    if (Array.isArray(src_json)){
        for (key in src_json){
            var sql_command =
            `INSERT INTO user_json_feedback (user,id,etype,region,date)//
            VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)`;
            snowflake.execute (
                {
                    sqlText: sql_command,
                    binds: [src_json[key].USER,src_json[key].ENTITY_ID,src_json[key].ENTITY_TYPE,REGION,curr_date]
                }
            );
            }
        }
    else {
        var sql_command =
            `INSERT INTO user_json_feedback (user,id,etype,region,date)//
            VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)`;
            snowflake.execute (
                {
                    sqlText: sql_command,
                    binds: [src_json.USER,src_json.ENTITY_ID,src_json.ENTITY_TYPE,REGION,curr_date]
                }
            );
        }
    return "Succeeded.";   // Return a success/error indicator.
    }
catch (err)  {
    return "Failed: " + err;   // Return a success/error indicator.
    }
$$;    

--Need to cast variable string as variant.
--ARRAY example
call SP_UPDATE_JSON_DATA ('[{"USER":"XYZ","ENTITY_ID":"BMT0001","ENTITY_TYPE":"BMT"},{"USER":"ABC","ENTITY_ID":"BMT0002","ENTITY_TYPE":"BMT"}]'::VARIANT);
--Single object example
call SP_UPDATE_JSON_DATA ('{"USER":"JST","ENTITY_ID":"BMT0003","ENTITY_TYPE":"BMT"}'::VARIANT);

SELECT *
FROM user_json_feedback;
```

Result set:
[image: result set]

While all this works, you may well be better served just inserting the whole variant into a table and relying on snowflake's significant semi-structured data querying capabilities. Certainly for large payloads you'll find much better performance from bulk loading to a variant column in a table then parsing in a view.